# Online/Offline Notification in Node.js like Facebook notification system

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, notifications

I am working on implementing the notification system in Node.js something similar to Facebook notification system. I have seen some implementations using Socket.io, but I don't know if it would be suitable for my situation. Another way I was thinking of doing it was create a Notification model (I am using MongoDB as the storage) something like this:

```
var Notification = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {type: String},
    added: {type: Date},
    accountId: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId},
    notificationType: {type: String},
    isSeen: {type: Boolean}
});
```

Then, I will use this in my account schema:

```
var AccountSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email:     { type: String, unique: true },
    password:  { type: String },
    name: {
        first:   { type: String },
        last:    { type: String },
        full: {type: String}
    },
    notifications: [Notification]
});
```

Then, i will do some sort of adding the notifications to users depending on the actions. However, i am not so sure if this approach would work well. Thus, I was wondering which approach would be best for this type of situation: **online/offline notification**.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You should really be looking into a Publish/Subscriber system for live notification.

In the case you encounter a subscriber that is offline, you could store on your [Notification] schema. Once the user connects again it can query them and acknowledge that they were seem.

resources:

[Publish Subscriber pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern)

[Redis Pub/Sub](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub)